# How can I easily read many Maildir directories?

Tags: files, email, maildir

I have about 40 Maildir directories in `/var/vmail/` with the structure of

```
Domain1.com
-- user
----- new
----- cur
----- tmp

Domain2.com
-- user
----- new
----- cur
----- tmp
```

Inside each of those `new`, `cur`, `tmp` directories there are email files. What can I use, configure, and how, to read those emails in an easy manner, not via the editor?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mutt -f /var/vmail/.../.maildir` to read the respective maildirs. But be aware that this will probably change the state of the maildir by moving mails e.g. from `new` to `cur`. The `-R` option starts mutt in read-only mode and prevents this.

Comment: Is there a webmail client that can do exactly that?